# C#: Shall I learn XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

Before you hate, sorry. But xna is being stopped supported, however I like c# and this seems like a nice library. Shall I learn it and port it to windows 8 with some stuff or shall I learn some else library. Or even some else programming language. I know java a bit as well, but I dont like lwjgl so I use only javas native libraries. I also know basics of ActionScript 3.0 but I like to have control over my games.

Comment: Your question doesn't fit here. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: Checkout monogame, it is a reimplementation of most of the XNA library and I believe they have done some work to get it working in store apps. http://www.monogame.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like XNA, you might want to take a look at [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net).
It should have the same api as XNA and supposedly has support for multiple platforms ( iOS, Android, Mac OS X, Linux, Windows, Windows 8 Store, and Windows Phone 8 ).

Comment: Supposedly? MonoGame definately does -- it's been used in the wild for many a cross-platform game (Fez, Rogue Legacy, and Wizorb, just to name a few).